# Empty variables when calling javascript function

Tags: javascript

I have a function as below.

I am trying to call this with

```
var testVar =  new genericYiiLocation();
console.log(testVar.getLongitude());
```

however, I this.getLongitude() always has an empty this.longitude.

I have checked that this.longitude contains the values as expected when being set in locateSuccess(loc) and it seems ok.

Any guidance would be appreciated.

```
function genericYiiLocation() {

    console.log('genericYiiLocation: Creating location handler');

    this.longitude=  '';
    this.latitude=   '';
    this.accuracy=   '';

    if (Modernizr.geolocation) {
        console.log('genericYiiLocation: Location supported');
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(locateSuccess, locateFail);
        }
        else {
            alert('genericYiiLocation: Geolocation is not supported in your current browser.');
            return false;
        }
    } else {
        alert ('genericYiiLocation: no native location support');
        return false;
    }


     function locateSuccess(loc){
        console.log('genericYiiLocation: storing location data');
        this.longitude = loc.coords.longitude;
    }

    // Unsuccessful geolocation
    function locateFail(geoPositionError) {
        switch (geoPositionError.code) {
            case 0: // UNKNOWN_ERROR
                alert('An unknown error occurred, sorry');
                break;
            case 1: // PERMISSION_DENIED
                alert('Permission to use Geolocation was denied');
                break;
            case 2: // POSITION_UNAVAILABLE
                alert('Couldn\'t find you...');
                break;
            case 3: // TIMEOUT
                alert('The Geolocation request took too long and timed out');
                break;
            default:
        }
    }

    this.getLongitude = function(){
        console.log('long: '+this.longitude);
        return this.longitude;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand the reason is:

The `this` inside your callback `locateSuccess` is different from the `this` outside the callback. To achieve what you are intending to, you can bind the callbacks `localSuccess` & `locateFail` to `this` using `Function.prototype.bind`.

Comment: Would you please have an example of how to do this ?

Comment: Your line `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(locateSuccess, locateFail);` should be changed to `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(locateSuccess.bind(this), locateFail.bind(this));`

Note that even though `Function.prototype.bind` is introduced in Javascript 1.8.5 & might not be supported in old browsers (like IE6), I'm thinking it would be supported in all browsers supporting geolocation (an HTML5 feature).

Comment: i have tried this with the same outcome. ie: this.longitude is still empty

I now have

    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(locateSuccess.bind(this), locateFail.bind(this));

Comment: It is working fine for me Just to be on same page, here is my usage:
`var a = new genericYiiLocation();
console.log(a.getLongitude());`

Note that the keyword `new` is important.

Answer (score 0):

The following line:

```
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(locateSuccess, locateFail);
```

causes your `locateSuccess` function to be executed in the *global* scope of your page. Hence, when the `locateSuccess` function tries to access `this`, it references the `window` object instead of your `genericYiiLocation` object.

A quick way to fix this would be to bind the `genericYiiLocation` object to another variable in its scope, then reference it within the `locateSuccess` closure like so:

```
function genericYiiLocation() {

    console.log('genericYiiLocation: Creating location handler');

    this.longitude=  '';
    this.latitude=   '';
    this.accuracy=   '';

    //  ADDED
    var me = this;

    if (Modernizr.geolocation) {
        console.log('genericYiiLocation: Location supported');
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(locateSuccess, locateFail);
        }
        else {
            alert('genericYiiLocation: Geolocation is not supported in your current browser.');
            return false;
        }
    } else {
        alert ('genericYiiLocation: no native location support');
        return false;
    }


    function locateSuccess(loc){
        console.log('genericYiiLocation: storing location data');
        //  CHANGED
        me.longitude = loc.coords.longitude;
    }

    // Unsuccessful geolocation
    function locateFail(geoPositionError) {
        switch (geoPositionError.code) {
            case 0: // UNKNOWN_ERROR
                alert('An unknown error occurred, sorry');
                break;
            case 1: // PERMISSION_DENIED
                alert('Permission to use Geolocation was denied');
                break;
            case 2: // POSITION_UNAVAILABLE
                alert('Couldn\'t find you...');
                break;
            case 3: // TIMEOUT
                alert('The Geolocation request took too long and timed out');
                break;
            default:
        }
    }

    this.getLongitude = function(){
        console.log('long: '+this.longitude);
        return this.longitude;
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems to work fine on my end - make sure that you see `genericYiiLocation: storing location data` in your console *before* your call to `getLongitude`. `genericYiiLocation` should really be doing all processing asynchronously, anyways.

Comment: Peter,

Thanks for that. Works perfectly. I now see the issue with scope and async nature of the calls. your callback is great. thanks

Comment: Glad to help. Please upvote and accept the answer if it's the one that worked for you!

Comment: peter, would be happy to but cant figure out how :-)

im new to this

Comment: lol...i cant..my reputation is too low :-( i only just joined